# How to sync React Router Params with state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Using React Router Web.

Assume we have a route: `/:user?showDetails=true`. We know how to **get** the data from the URL with the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook and something like the [`useQuery`](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) custom hook.

Also, we know how to **set** this data with [`history.push(/baruchiro?showDetails=false)`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history).

But if we get and set this data, and in case we don't use this to redirect the user from one page to another, but to change the current component (to let the user save its current page view), it's mean that the **route** is **state**.

How can I use the route as a state without getting the component dirty with a lot of `history.push` and `useParams`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update

I published this custom hook as *npm package*: [use-route-as-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-route-as-state)

---

If you want to use the `route` as `state`, you need a way to **get** the route params, and also **update** them.

You can't avoid using `history.push` since this is the way you change your "state", your `route`. But you can hide this command for cleaner code.

Here is an example of how to hide the **get** and the **update** in custom hooks, that make them to looks like a regular `useState` hook:

**To use *Query Params* as state:**

```js
import { useHistory, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

const useQueryAsState = () => {
    const { pathname, search } = useLocation()
    const history = useHistory()

    // helper method to create an object from URLSearchParams
    const params = getQueryParamsAsObject(search)

    const updateQuery = (updatedParams) => {
        Object.assign(params, updatedParams)
        // helper method to convert {key1:value,k:v} to '?key1=value&k=v'
        history.replace(pathname + objectToQueryParams(params))
    }

    return [params, updateQuery]
}
```

**To use *Route Params* as state:**

```js
import { generatePath, useHistory, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom'

const useParamsAsState = () => {
    const { path, params } = useRouteMatch()
    const history = useHistory()

    const updateParams = (updatedParams) => {
        Object.assign(params, updatedParams)
        history.push(generatePath(path, params))
    }
    return [params, updateParams]
}
```

> Note to the `history.replace` in the *Query Params* code and to the `history.push` in the *Route Params* code.

**Usage:** (Not a real component from my code, sorry if there are compilation issues)

```js
const ExampleComponent = () => {
    const [{ user }, updateParams] = useParamsAsState()
    const [{ showDetails }, updateQuery] = useQueryAsState()

    return <div>
        {user}<br/ >{showDetails === 'true' && 'Some details'}
        <DropDown ... onSelect={(selected) => updateParams({ user: selected }) />
        <Checkbox ... onChange={(isChecked) => updateQuery({ showDetails: isChecked} })} />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I need help to publish a package for that https://github.com/baruchiro/use-route-as-state

Comment: Your famous `objectToQueryParams` function can simply be a wrapper around `URLSearchParams`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: cool but [doesn't work with react router v6 yet](https://github.com/baruchiro/use-route-as-state/issues/172)

Answer (score 1):

I created the following NPM package to store state using URL search params with `react-router-dom-v6`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-search-params-state